# How to solve the "No module named 'ConfigParser'" issue in every of my installation

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, configparser

I have a ubuntu 16.0.4 system, that has both python 2 and python3 installed, and here is the version of each python.

```
python --version
Python 2.7.12
python3 --version
Python 3.7.6
```

Now, I don't know since when, If I was to install any package using apt-get I am getting this type of error, which has nothing to do with the package I am installing now:

```
apt-get install -y nodejs

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libglib2.0-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libglib2.0-dev nodejs
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 187 not upgraded.
104 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/27.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 53.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 148506 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-dev_2.48.2-0ubuntu4.8_amd64.deb ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-dev_2.48.2-0ubuntu4.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-dev_2.48.2-0ubuntu4.8_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am clueless how to have this issue resolved. Any idea how this can be resolved.

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Can you please retry by installing/executing the following packages `apt-get install python3-dev`

Comment: Thanks for the tips. But still no good. Any idea why that is being triggered ?